# На логотипе сайта в списке чат-комнат всё ещё висит beta

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, чат, аттестация

Если посмотреть список чат-комнат следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то можно увидеть, что логотип сайта всё ещё старый (sackoverflow beta)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Та же проблема внутри чат-комнаты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно там эту ссылку

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/ru/img/logo.png?v=cc
```

заменить этой

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/ru/img/logo.png
```